# Rename Package with Sub-packages in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-7

I Know this seems absurd to ask but I can't seem to get around renaming a package in Netbeans that Have sub-packages. ideally when I right-click and refactor > Rename it renames only the node on the Top. If I try to refactor the Next Node in Line, I get the Error that :

```
Package already Exists
```

Does anyone knows how i should go about renaming my main package containing other packages and sub-packages in Netbeans? I am using netbeans 7.2.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using Netbeans 7.3 and assuming your project has the following structure:

```
my.package.test.subpackage1
my.package.test.subpackage2
my.package.test.subpackage3
```

You want to rename `test` into `tests`.

Go to the NetBeans `Files` window (`Ctrl + 2` or using the `Window -> Files` menu). Left-click on the folder corresponding to the package you want to rename (i.e. `test`).
Type `F2` and rename it.

All the sub-packages should have been moved to the new directory **and** all the related `package` and `import` statements should have been updated.

Comment: great, but be aware: all the imports with the asterisc in the same project will not be converted in netbeans